# How create a multi sum() for one table with group by and different type for one person

Tags: mysql

I have a complicated mysql table, like:

```
staff     type      value       date

  a       cash       10      2013-02-17
  b       efpos       5      2013-02-16
  c       voucher    20      2013-02-16
  a       cash       10      2013-02-16
  b       efpos       5      2013-02-16
  c       voucher    20      2013-02-15
  a       cash       10      2013-02-15
  b       efpos       5      2013-02-15
  c       voucher    20      2013-02-14
```

How can I get a table like this?

```
staff     cash      efpos       voucher              total                 date
   a       sum       sum          sum      sum(cash, efpos, voucher)    2013-02-16
   b       sum       sum          sum      sum(cash, efpos, voucher)    2013-02-16
   c       sum       sum          sum      sum(cash, efpos, voucher)    2013-02-16
```

It means I want to get the **separated sum** for each type using **group by** staff and date, and also with a total for this three types.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work.

```
SELECT staff,
SUM(CASE type WHEN 'cash' THEN value ELSE 0 END) as cash,
SUM(CASE type WHEN 'efpos' THEN value ELSE 0 END) as efpos,
SUM(CASE type WHEN 'voucher' THEN value ELSE 0 END) as voucher,
SUM(value) as total

FROM <TABLE_NAME>

GROUP BY staff
```

However, you can't get the date when using aggregate functions. Nor would it make sense to do so, since you are not using group by on the date, but the staff instead.